# Что модераторы могут делать с голосами?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, голоса-против, голоса-за

Вроде где-то читал, что модераторы могут просматривать, кто голосовал за ответ или вопрос.

А так же, что они могут что-то сделать со стратегическим выставлением минусов. По крайней мере, в вопросе об этом была рекомендация ставить тревогу модераторам.

Но сейчас встретил [комментарий](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317770/what-to-do-when-a-user-totally-copied-an-answer-and-behaving-like-a-troll-on-a-q#comment314161_317771) модератора [Brad Larson ♦](//meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson), где говорится, что модераторы не видят, кто голосовал:

> I should say that we can't do anything about someone downvoting all the answers to a question. If they're not targeting someone, we can't see who voted, nor can we change those votes.

Действительно ли это так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, о каких модераторах идет речь? Не каждый участник сообщества с ромбом у имени является модератором. Часть из них сотрудники компании (причем, у разных сотрудников разные права на разных сайтах).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, но ведь все сотрудники обладают правами не меньше, чем избранные модераторы?

Comment: Нет. Например, на AskUbuntu я – рядовой участник. Более того, у разных сотрудников могут быть разные «права модератора». Например, у нескольких «модераторов от компании» есть возможность запускать скрипты, которые делают что–то  (к примеру, они могут запустить скрипт пересчета голосов или репутации).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, какой-то странный ромбик, получается. Зачем показывать его у того, кто не обладает особыми привилегиями?

Comment: Да, странный! Но у меня нет ромба на AskUbuntu. На Stack Overflow на русском я могу чуть больше чем модераторы выбранные сообществом, но запускать скрипты по базе приходится коллег.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, так всё-таки (раз там ромба нет), верно ли, что любой участник, у которого отображается ромб, имеет как минимум возможности избранного модератора? Если не верно, то, пожалуй, надо отдельным вопросом спрашивать :)

Comment: Да, верно. Есть ромб – есть права модератора.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Несколько фактов:

- [Менеджер сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) может увидеть, кто голосовал за/против конкретный вопрос или ответ, за исключением собственных вопросов и ответов.
- [Модераторы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) не могут этого увидеть.
- И менеджер и модераторы могут увидеть общую раскладку голосования конкретного участника: за/против чьих сообщений (вопросов + ответов) он голосовал и кто голосовал за/против его сообщения. Там и там показываются только участники с существенной долей голосов.
- Модераторы могут откатить голоса (и репутацию) только путём удаления учётной записи, с которой были отданы эти голоса. У менеджера сообщества есть инструменты, чтобы откатить голоса без удаления учётной записи.

Таким образом, на основании агрегированных данных можно обнаружить только ситуации, когда один участник систематически голосует за или против другого. Далеко не всегда это плохо или требует вмешательства модератора. Например, у огромного числа участников существенная часть голосов отдана за ответы VladD. Причина не в том, что VladD — злостный ботовод, а в том, что он дает много хороших ответов.

Так называемое «стратегическое выставление минусов» — довольно неоднозначная штука. Как уже не раз говорили, участник может вполне честно ставить минусы ответам, которые считает плохими, и публиковать собственные ответы. Ничего предосудительного в этом нет.

Comment: Впервые встречаю термин "менеджер сообщества". Это кто? Сотрудник компании?

Comment: @Qwertiy Community Manager. У нас это Nicolas Chabanovsky.

Comment: @Qwertiy «Менеджер сообщества» – крайний за сообщество сотрудник компании. Его/её задача – быть двунаправленным мостом соединяющим сообщество и компанию, то есть представлять интересы сообщества в кругу сотрудников и, в то же время, интересы компании в сообществе.

Comment: _"за/против чьих ответов он голосовал и кто голосовал за/против его ответы"_ - это с вопросами, или агрегированные данные?

Comment: @Qwertiy уточнил. Речь о вопросах и ответах суммарно.